# My model is not binding during submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm practicing MVC ASP.net and I am having a problem. During load, I get the data and passed it to model for display and try to pass it again for posting to save the data but then the model is not getting the data.Please help me for what I am missing. Thank you

I attached an image, what does it display and those data should get on posting.

My Model

```
public class RoomReservation
    {
        public RoomReservation()
        {
            AddAmenity = new List<AmenityReservation>();
        }

        public int Room_id { get; set; }
        public string Room_name { get; set; }
        public int RoomType_id { get; set; }
        public string Room_Type { get; set; }
        public decimal Room_rate { get; set; }

        public List<AmenityReservation> AddAmenity { get; set; }

    }

    public class AmenityReservation
    {
        public int Amenity_id { get; set; }
        public string Amenity_Name { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amenity_Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
        public ActionResult RoomReservation(int RoomID)
        {
            RoomReservationEntities db = new RoomReservationEntities();
            var model = new RoomReservation();

            model.Room_id = RoomID;
            model.Room_name = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.Room_id == RoomID).Select(r => r.Room_name).FirstOrDefault();
            model.RoomType_id = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.Room_id == RoomID).Select(r => r.Room_Type.RoomType_id).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Room_Type = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.Room_id == RoomID).Select(r => r.Room_Type.RoomType).FirstOrDefault();
            model.Room_rate = db.Rooms.Where(x => x.Room_id == RoomID).Select(r => r.Room_Type.Room_rate).FirstOrDefault();

            var amenities = db.Amenities.ToList();

            foreach (var n in amenities)
            {
                model.AddAmenity.Add(new AmenityReservation { Amenity_id = n.Amenity_id, Amenity_Name = n.Amenity1, Amenity_Price = n.Price, Quantity = 0 });
            }

            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RoomReservation(RoomReservation model)
        {
            //here the model is not binding from display

            return View();
        }
```

My View

```
@model Reservation_System.Models.RoomReservation

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RoomReservation";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<div style="padding-top:10%">

</div>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <section class="container tm-home-section-1" id="more">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                        <h2>RoomReservation</h2>
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Room_id)
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Room_Type)
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Room_rate)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="visibility:hidden"></td>
                                <td>Amenity</td>
                                <td>Price</td>
                                <td>Quantity</td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var n in Model.AddAmenity)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="visibility:hidden">@n.Amenity_id</td>
                                    <td>@n.Amenity_Name</td>
                                    <td>@n.Amenity_Price</td>
                                    <td><input type="text" value="@n.Quantity" /> </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Reserve" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
}
```

Display in view and data should pass during posting for saving in the database

[image]

Comment: The only form control in the form dos not even have a `name` attribute, so its value is never even submitted. And never generate your form controls manually - always use the `HtmlHelper` methods. And a `foreach` loop would never work anyway - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: `<td><input type="text" name=@n.Quantity value="@n.Quantity" /> </td>` Give here the name

Comment: @aakash - that would have no relationship at all to the model!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have the name on your attribute Html. So, while you post the form to controller, the value does not bind to the property on the model.

Change your loop for `ameniety` with the code as below.

```
<tbody>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AddAmenity.Count; i++)
{
  <tr>

    <td>@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AddAmenity[i].Amenity_id)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddAmenity[i].Amenity_Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddAmenity[i].Amenity_Price, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddAmenity[i].Quantity)</td>
  </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

If you also wanted to submit the value from `Room_id`, `Room_Type` and `Room_rate`. Either use the

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Room_id)
```

Or

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Room_id) 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Room_id)
```

So on, for type and rate.

You need to use `HiddenFor` and `DisplayFor` because

`HiddenFor` is used to have the values ready to be posted, and `DisplayFor` to show those values.

Refer:

1. [MVC4 Razor - @Html.DisplayFor not binding to model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056954/mvc4-razor-html-displayfor-not-binding-to-model/11057087#11057087)
2. [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)