# ASP.NET MVC 5 - LabelFor displays property name instead of value, but TextBoxFor works fine with the same property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on a view with `IList<MyModel>` model assigned and I'm stuck at displaying values with `LabelFor` (property name instead of its value is displayed), however, everything works fine with  `TextBoxFor` even when it's used with the same property.

Part of the view code:

```cs
@model IList<MyModel>

  @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Code)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Price)</td>
        </tr>
   }
```

Model class:

```cs
public class MyModel
  {
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
  }
```

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Code)` also works fine so the issue is apparently not related to the property itself.

I could use just `Label()`, but I need to POST the values from a form, so I also have to add a hidden field for `Code` and I feel it's not the most elegant solution.

Why `TextBoxFor` works, but `LabelFor` doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LabelFor` displays the *name* of the field (it's used to create a label for a control).

If you want to display the *value* of a field, use `DisplayFor`:

```html
<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Code)</td>
    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Price)</td>
</tr>
```

**Note:** `DisplayFor` just displays a text value (like a label) which isn't included when the form is submitted.  If you need the value to be returned with the form/model, then you need to add a hidden field.  You can use `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Code)` which will create a hidden input rendered like `<input type="hidden" name="myModels[0].Code" value="abc" />`.

Comment: Model binding does not work when using `DisplayFor`, but your answer helped me find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11057087/8297552. It seems that hidden field is necessary: "You could accomplish this with a duo of HiddenFor and DisplayFor. Use HiddenFor to have the values ready to be posted, and DisplayFor to show those values"

Comment: @ŁukaszSypniewski Yeah, you will need to add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Code)` to pass the value back to the controller since `DisplayFor` doesn't do that automatically.  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `LabelFor` defines the expression that identifies the property to display and the second parameter displays the texl label.

> [LabelExtensions.LabelFor Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.labelextensions.labelfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m[i].Code, Model[i].Code)</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Price)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: It turns out that the `LabelFor` values are not POSTed from a form which I was not aware of, so I have to stay with hidden field anyway.

Comment: There are several ways to do this as well, and of course you can write your own customize Helper